# how to update the count number in one screen from the get value of other screen in angular2

Tags: angular

i have a side bar which is common for all pages, and i have totally 12 screens in that.
In sidebar, i need to get the count of records particular page has.
Right now it is working, but after page refresh.
Can anyone help me to sort this.

Screen1:

```
getList() {
    let params = { 'Id': Id, PageNo:pageNo, PageSize: 10 }
    this.Service.getEmr(params)
      .subscribe(Lists => {
        this.list = Lists.Body.Data.Items;
        this.count = Lists.Body.Data.TotalItemCount;
        console.log(this.count);
      })
  }
```

Same get method i had added to the side bar and assigning count value in the html.

Here in screen1, i have 3 data, so in side bar also count is 3, if i add one more item in screen1, it becomes 4 items in screen1, but in side bar 3 items are shown, after page refresh it is getting updated.

Comment: where you are calling getList()??

Comment: @UnluckyAj Thanks for response, i am calling that method in both the screens, screen1 and in side bar

Comment: can you elaborate something more about what you want??

Comment: ya i will update in question.